Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class graphql.schema.GraphQLTypeReference cannot be cast to class graphql.schema.GraphQLUnmodifiedType
I have a java class as type in graphql schema for example it is
input User {
    age: Float
    name: String
}

and
input SaveUsersInput{
    users: [User]
}

when the SaveUsersInput is unwrapped by the
/**
* Unwraps all layers of the type or just returns the type again if it's not a wrapped type
* NOTE: This method does not support GraphQLTypeReference as input and will lead to a ClassCastException
*
* @param type the type to unwrapOne
*
* @return the underlying type
*/
public static GraphQLUnmodifiedType unwrapAll(GraphQLType type) {
return unwrapAllAs(type);
}
The User is treated like GraphQLTypeReference and that is why it failed.
But as in the schema cannot be removed the usage of arrays
How can I fixed this problem:
This is the error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class graphql.schema.GraphQLTypeReference cannot be cast to class graphql.schema.GraphQLUnmodifiedType (graphql.schema.GraphQLTypeReference and graphql.schema.GraphQLUnmodifiedType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at graphql.schema.GraphQLTypeUtil.unwrapAll(GraphQLTypeUtil.java:194)
    at graphql.validation.util.DirectivesAndTypeWalker.walkInputType(DirectivesAndTypeWalker.java:23)
    at graphql.validation.util.DirectivesAndTypeWalker.walkInputType(DirectivesAndTypeWalker.java:41)
    at graphql.validation.util.DirectivesAndTypeWalker.isSuitable(DirectivesAndTypeWalker.java:19)
    at graphql.validation.constraints.AbstractDirectiveConstraint.appliesTo(AbstractDirectiveConstraint.java:72)
    at graphql.validation.rules.ValidationRules.lambda$getRulesFor$0(ValidationRules.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:178)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at graphql.validation.rules.ValidationRules.getRulesFor(ValidationRules.java:82)
    at graphql.validation.rules.ValidationRules.buildRulesFor(ValidationRules.java:72)
    at graphql.validation.schemawiring.ValidationSchemaWiring.onField(ValidationSchemaWiring.java:39)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.directive.DirectiveWiringHelper$wireFields$1$2$1.invoke(DirectiveWiringHelper.kt:60)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.directive.DirectiveWiringHelper$wireFields$1$2$1.invoke(DirectiveWiringHelper.kt:60)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.directive.DirectiveWiringHelper.wireDirectives(DirectiveWiringHelper.kt:87)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.directive.DirectiveWiringHelper.wireFields(DirectiveWiringHelper.kt:60)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.directive.DirectiveWiringHelper.wireObject(DirectiveWiringHelper.kt:24)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser.createObject(SchemaParser.kt:154)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser.parseSchemaObjects(SchemaParser.kt:84)
    at graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser.makeExecutableSchema(SchemaParser.kt:113)
    at graphql.kickstart.autoconfigure.tools.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.graphQLSchema(GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.java:154)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146)
    ... 124 common frames omitted

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>15.1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>15.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>graphql-java-extended-scalars</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.github.graphql-java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>graphql-java-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


       <graphql.spring.boot.starter.version>15.1.0</graphql.spring.boot.starter.version>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
                <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
                <version>13.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
     


        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
                <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${graphql.spring.boot.starter.version}</version>
            </dependency>

I think that there should be excluded something from the dependencies I searched but could not found
